# What does //noinspection ForLoopReplaceableByForEach mean?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have been reading some open source libraries which use the following code:

```
//noinspection ForLoopReplaceableByForEach
for (int i = 0, count = list.size(); i < count; i++) {
  // do something
}
```

What does `//noinspection ForLoopReplaceableByForEach` mean?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`//noinspection` is an IntelliJ specific annotation. It's similar to Java's `@SupressWarnings` except that it can be used for a single statement instead of declaring it at class or method level as `@SupressWarnings`.

In this case, it is suppressing the warning that the For loop could be replaced by a ForEach.

Answer (score 3):

It means that you're using a counter to run through the list, when you could just do:

```
for (Object obj : list)
```

where Object is replaced by the type of the Object in list.